# javascript grid sort by number, ordering issue

Tags: javascript, sorting, grid

I have a JS sort script, but is ordering #'s like this:

```
1.
10.
11.
2.
3.
4.
```

I want them to be ordered by value, like this:

```
1.
2.
3.
4.
10.
11.
```

I cannot figure this out. I know there is a way to do it with MySQL, but I am unfamiliar with javascript. Here is what I have so far, but it is ordering numeric numbers incorrect. I appreciate any help you can provide, or just shooting me the right direction.

**JavaScript:**

```
var Grid = new Class({
    /** define some variables */
    table: false, 
    headers: false, 
    data: false, 

    /**
     * Initialize the object
     */
    initialize: function(table){
        this.table = table;
        this.getHeaders();
    }, 

    /**
     * Get the headers
     */
    getHeaders: function(){
        this.headers = this.table.getElements('thead tr th');
        this.headers.each(function(h, index){
            //h.store('asc', false);
            if (h.hasClass('sort')) h.addEvent('click', function(){
                if(h.hasClass('asc')){
                    h.className = 'sort desc';

                    //h.addClassName('desc');
                }else{
                    h.className = 'sort asc';
                    //h.addClassName('asc');
                }
                //if (h.retrieve('asc')) h.store('asc', false);
                //else h.store('asc', true);
                //this.sort($('tblrank_id'));
                this.sort(index);
            }.bind(this));
        }, this);
    }, 

    /**
     * Get the table data
     */
    getData: function(){
        this.data = this.table.getElements('tbody tr');
    }, 

    /**
     * Sort the data
     * @param int index
     */
    sort: function(index){
        this.getData();
        data = [];
        sortType = this.headers[index].getProperty('axis');

        asc = this.headers[index].hasClass('asc');//this.headers[index].retrieve('asc');
        if (this.data.length > 0) this.data.each(function(row, i){
            cells = row.getElements('td');
            if (cells.length < this.headers.length) return false;
            value = cells[index].innerHTML;

            if(cells[index].childNodes[0].nodeName.toLowerCase() == "a"){
                //alert(cells[index].childNodes[0].innerHTML);
                value = cells[index].childNodes[0].innerHTML;
            }

            if (sortType == 'int' || sortType == 'float'){
                if (value.contains('$') || value.contains(',')) value = value.replace(/\$/g, '').replace(/,/g, '').toFloat();
                else value = value.toFloat();
            } else if (sortType == 'date') value = Date.parse(value);
            data.push({'index': i, 'value': value, 'row': row});
        }, this);

        if (sortType == 'int' || sortType == 'float' || sortType == 'date') data.sort(this.sortNumeric);
        else data.sort(this.sortCaseInsensitive);
        if (!asc) data.reverse();

        this.data = [];
        data.each(function(d, i){
            this.data.push(d.row);
        }, this);

        this.data.each(function(row, i){
            if (row.hasClass('etblraw0')) row.removeClass('etblraw0');
            if (row.hasClass('etblraw1')) row.removeClass('etblraw1');
            this.table.getElement('tbody').adopt(row.addClass((i % 2 == 0 ? 'etblraw0' : 'etblraw1')));


        }, this);
    }, 

    /**
     * Sort Numerica Values
     * @param object a
     * @param object b
     */
    sortNumeric: function(a, b){


        if ($type(a.value) != 'number') a.value = 0;
        if ($type(b.value) != 'number') b.value = 0;
        return a.value - b.value;
    }, 

    sortCaseInsensitive: function(a, b){
        a.value = a.value.toLowerCase();


        b.value = b.value.toLowerCase();
        if (a.value == b.value) return 0;
        if (a.value < b.value) return -1;
        return 1;
    }
);
```

Comment: If would you create live working example on http://jsfiddle.net it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function sortfunc(a,b) {
  return parseInt(a.split(".")[0]) -
         parseInt(b.split(".")[0]);
}

var list = ["1. first", "2. second", "10. tenth"];
list.sort(sortfunc);

console.log(list); // => ["1. first", "2. second", "10. tenth"]
```

Comment: tried cutting and pasting this in the bottom, by the SortNumeric code section above. Couldn't make it work. I added my full code. Thank you for the help

Comment: @user1071915 the issue is that your numbers are sorting as strings. Calling `parseInt` is the important part of this response. @Riateche why not just use the radix, like `parstInt(a, 10)`?

Comment: @Josh I think it's more clear to pass only number to `parseInt` and cut off the rest. If I'd write `parseInt(a, 10)`, someone can think that I've made a mistake because string `a` does not respesent a number.

Comment: @Riateche I guess I'm just used to Python where a trailing dot is used to convert ints to floats.

Comment: @Riateche—you can get rid of the split, `parseInt` trims any non-numeric characters from the end of the string, the sort function can just be `return parseInt(a, 10) - parseInt(b, 10);`. Or you can do the split and forget `parseInt` since the subraction will coerce the vaulues to numbers anyway. But `parseInt` is likely faster.